# SSIS Visual Studio: SSL provider the certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

When I am trying to connect to SQL Server in SSIS I am getting the following error but I am able to connect to the same SQL Server in SSMS.
The Error Message is "ssl provider the certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted".

Comment: Please post errors as text, not images.

Comment: This is the Error message "ssl provider the certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted". It is getting in SSIS Visual Studio.

Comment: Edit it into your question - not as a comment

Comment: Have you tried reading [Release notes for the Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/release-notes-for-oledb-driver-for-sql-server)? As with ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server and JDBC 10.2 Driver for SQL Server, OLE DB Driver 19 for SQL Server includes a _breaking change_ that changes the previous `Encrypt=false/no` default to `Encrypt=true/yes`. This is problematic for default installs of SQL Server because the default X.509 certificate is self-signed, so not trusted by any recognized CA.

Comment: Can you please tell me the solution to get rid of this? @AlwaysLearning

Comment: @NaidsonHari, either [provision a certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-encrypted-connections-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16) on the database server or add [TrustServerCertificate=yes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) to the connection string. The former is the most secure solution.

Comment: @NaidsonHari your response resolved my problem, many thanks!